# Why does Flash Builder 4.6 Profiler seem to leak Strings, whereas Debug mode GC's as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

While unit profiling my classes I noticed that the String class endlessly accumulates (eating up over 90% of the memory in my sizable app). Luckily this is *only* while running in *Profiler* mode of Flash Builder 4.6. In debug or deployment (as AIR) memory usage levels off as expected using embedded on-screen memory profilier (Mr Doobs Stats).

To verify I made a test app that was simply a URLLoader continuously loading a text file. When running in Profilier mode using URLLoaderDataFormat.String the String data is never GC'd and grows continuously whereas using URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY the data is nearly immediately GC'd and stays level.

I hesitate to call this a bug, because possibly it's necessary part of the way the Profilier works… but perhaps this is abnormal for the Profiler? This is the essence of my StackOverflow inquiry.

At any rate, this burned up a couple work-days for me, so if you're Googling wondering why the String class is growing like crazy and never getting GC'd consider measuring your apps memory usage outside the Profilier to verify. In my case I was mislead into thinking I had run into some problem with Master Strings — though it's good understand Master Strings and their impact on memory ([see:](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3alMfXUk1B6LgJ%3ajunkbyte.com/wp/as3/flash-string-weirdness/%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)) don't get mislead like I did.